# RxJS groupBy with NgRx selector never completes

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store

Retrieving a list of fixtures from my API, I am attempting to group these fixtures by their date, which works when I call the service directly in my component, but not when I am selecting the fixtures from the store.

The following outputs 2 arrays - ie 2 groups of fixtures based on their date:

```
this.store.pipe(
  select(selectCurrentSeasonId)
).subscribe(seasonId =>  {
  this.fixtureService.getFixtures(seasonId).pipe(
    mergeMap(fixtures => fixtures),
    groupBy(fixture => fixture.matchDate),
    mergeMap(group => group.pipe(toArray())),
    tap(res => console.log(res))
  ).subscribe(fixtures => this.fixtures$ = fixtures);
```

However, when using a store selector for the fixtures rather than the service call, I get no output:

```
this.store.pipe(
  select(selectCurrentSeasonId)
).subscribe(seasonId =>  {
  this.store.dispatch(loadFixtures({seasonId}));
  this.store.pipe(
    select(selectAllFixtures),
    mergeMap(fixtures => fixtures),
    groupBy(fixture => fixture.matchDate),
    mergeMap(group => group.pipe(toArray())),
    tap(res => console.log(res))
  ).subscribe(fixtures => this.fixtures$ = fixtures);
});
```

If I move `tap()` to above the 2nd `mergeMap()` I get a GroupedObservable output in the console, but I can't iterate over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `toArray()` that emits only when its source Observable completes on an Observable that never completes (`this.store`). Each group emitted by `groupBy` completes when the source Observable completes or when an optional `durationSelector` emits (https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/groupBy). Since ngrx store never completes then each individual groups never complete either by themselves.

It looks like you might want to use `take(1)` after `select(selectAllFixtures)` because then you're using `mergeMap` to unpack the array to separated emissions.

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately, the take(1) produces an empty array if I move tap() to just after it, but the original tap() outputs nothing if take(1) is used

Comment: take(1) just takes the first emission whatever it is. So maybe you should filter out empty arrays with filter(...).